# Is it possible to accidentally overwrite "meta-data" in VkDeviceMemory?

Tags: vulkan

From the answer from this [reddit post](https://www.reddit.com/r/vulkan/comments/6uixdr/comment/dlt59yz/?utm_source=share&utm_medium=web2x&context=3).

> ...drivers may need some additional meta-data to manage given resource. That's why we need to call vkGet...MemoryRequirements() functions and allocate enough memory.

However, `vkMapMemory` maps the allocated memory, inside which the meta-data required by driver may be contained, according to the above answer.

When I write to that mapped memory, how am I supposed to know whether I am overwriting
the meta-data?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You should ignore that part of the post. It's nonsense.

Implementations may in fact need metadata for `VkBuffer` and `VkImage` objects. But that metadata is *not stored* within the `VkDeviceMemory` you provide when you bind those objects to the memory. They are associated with the `VkBuffer` and `VkImage` objects. They are allocated when those objects are constructed (which is why creating them takes a `VkAllocationCallbacks`) and deallocated when they are destroyed.

The purpose in querying the memory requirements for buffers and images is not for metadata associated with the buffer/image per-se. It's for layout purposes. Some buffer usages have to have specific alignments and the sizes may need to be rounded up to that alignment. Optimally-tiled images have a layout that is completely opaque; you're not allowed to directly write to the bytes of a tiled image. You can only copy into/outof them with image copy commands.